# How do I access one entry in a mail merge document?

Tags: vb.net, email, devexpress, mailmerge

I have set up a mail merged XtraReport, and it works fine. Now I want to access one entry in that mail merged report. By entry I mean the text associated with one row in the dataset, i.e. with the values filled in instead of having the square brackets with the field names.

So if have an XRRichText in my report with the text "Hi [name]" I want access to the XRRichText object with the RTF value "Hi Sandy"

Edit: Added information in example, added VB.net tag

Comment: how do you load the data? what programing language do you use?

Comment: @Ezi, I use a dataset in VB.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `GetCurrentColumnValue` method described [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIXtraReportBase_GetCurrentColumnValuetopic).

Comment: This returns values in the dataset, I'd like the text associated with the current row.

Comment: There are no rows in an xtrareport. There are only rows of data that are displayed on a report. The report itself is freeform. You can access the contents of a label control if you know its name. That may be what you want to do.

Comment: Yes but if I access the label control, I still get "Hi [name]" instead of "Hi Sandy" as in the example above. Is there no way to associate the label control to the data row?

Comment: Are you accessing the contents of the label AFTER the merge has taken place? If memory serves correctly you need to use the "BeforePrint" event as this is just before the text is output to the report surface. If that does not work you could use my previous suggestion (GetCurrentColumnValue) and look up the value of [name] in the data source and replace it manually.

Comment: Ah I see you have edited your question to include reference to a Rich Text box. This changes the question completely. Can you use http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIXRRichText_Linestopic

Comment: Yes, I realized that my example wasn't clear enough. I think you are right about doing manually. I was afraid it might come to that, so that is why I asked the question.
It seems that the merge is only done when the document is printed or previewed, I want to send this in an e-mail.